# Patterns for migration to multi-tenant application

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, multitenancy

I have a complex web application that  manages stores and their customers.

The application follows a basic MVC architecture and I should migrate it to a multi-tenant application:
- I should go from one store to more stores belonging the same company

- I will have a db for each store (one db with tenant_id is not an option)
- I would like to keep the existing interfaces, for example customer.getOrders(). But now "customer" must search on several stores/db. This would allow me keep most of the logic and presentation

It's not clear to me how what is the best pattern from an OOP point of view.

Should I have for example an interface Customer and then 2 implementations, CustomerSingle (the existing one) and CustomerMulti that contains a collection of CustomerSingle? Is there a known software pattern for this situation?

In other words, all the original classes will be still valid in the multi tenant situation but I must "aggregate" their result.

Comment: Keep in mind that transactions across multiple databases are problematical - and that using multiple databases will prevent you aggregating data where it can be done most efficiently - at the DB server...

Comment: I'm not very interested in transactions (90% is reading) and the solution with 1DB+tenant_id would imply a complete code rewrite, with no automated testing available....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Just looking for suggestions, experiences ...

Design for the new functionality. Without the big picture how can you - much less I - assess a microscopic issue like a Customer interface.

Once you see what you need you can better assess how the existing code base might change. Once you see what needs to change you can contemplate *how*.

Design is everything. If you start by ripping apart your code as random thoughts cross your mind, well, you're in for a world of hurt.

Comment: I agree with what you said but I tried to give just a small example. The need is clear for me: I want to make the transition from 1 DB to many in a way as transparent as possible for the original application...